# Is there any way to read the urls that are redirects in a get request?

Tags: python, python-requests

If I have a url and I make a get request, how would I be able to see all the urls it passes through before it reaches the destination?

Example:

```
import requests

Urlinp = input("Enter the URL ")

req = requests.get(url=Urlinp, allow_redirects=True)

for url in req:
print(url)
```

I need to be able to read and validate each url the request passes through

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`response.history`](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) shows the chain of redirections.

> ```
> >> r = requests.get('http://github.com/')
>
> >> r.url
> 'https://github.com/'
>
> >> r.status_code
> 200
>
> >> r.history
> [<Response [301]>]
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that any redirects actually occur? Try `allow_redirects=False` and see if you get any `30x` responses.